# ignite apache use vs mongo db use - main difference

Tags: database, mongodb, bigdata, ignite

Ignite vs mongo db

1. what are the main differences between ignite apache and mongo db?
2. is mongo db a data base that we keep in disk and ignite a memory we keep in Ram ?
3. and can you use them together? if yes, how will you combine them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If not to go into details, Ignite supports key-value and SQL access, while Mongo supports document-based access. Ignite supports transactions, while Mongo is eventually consistent. Ignite supports memory-only and memory with disk while Mongo only supports memory with disk
2. Starting version 2.0 Ignite provides it's own [distributed persistence](https://ignite.apache.org/features/persistence.html). Once the native persistence is enabled it will store a superset of all the data on disk. RAM will hold a subset or the same set of data for the sake of in-memory performance.
3. In addition to the native persistence, Ignite can use a [3rd party disk-based database](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store) including MongoDB. However, you have to consider [the following limitations](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store#section-overview) if you decide to use MongoDB instead of the native persistence in Ignite.

Comment: what is the difference between key-value and and document based access? isn't the same?